# Archive file in Script task using c# in ssis

Tags: ssis

I want to archive file with date  using Script task.filename will be like abc_x1.csv. file will be coming monthly once  next file comes like abc_x2.csv 
Need to archive the file with whatever name after _.csv with date before the extension. iam using the below code this is not working. can anyone help me on this.using C# code in script task.script task used inside the for each loop container.

```
public void Main()
        {   String sDateSuffix = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

            String ArchiveDir = Dts.Variables["V_ArchiveDir"].Value.ToString();          
             String FileName = Dts.Variables["V_FileName"].Value.ToString()+sDateSuffix;
              File.Move(Dts.Variables["V_FilePath"].Value.ToString() +FileName, ArchiveDir + FileName);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to append your sDateSuffix to your file name but before the .csv extension.  If so, I think you just need to use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension():

```
String sDateSuffix = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
String ArchiveDir = Dts.Variables["V_ArchiveDir"].Value.ToString();
String V_FileName = Dts.Variables["V_FileName"].Value.ToString();
//Assuming V_FileName = "abc_x1.csv", FileName will be "abc_x120150430080000.csv"
String FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(V_FileName) + sDateSuffix + Path.GetExtension(V_FileName);
```

Comment: Hi Bert,I tried that option but getting an error message.
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC0010009):

Comment: That message means that your ScriptTask can't find one of your SSIS variables.  When you open your ScriptTask componenet (but before you click the "Edit Script" button), do you have the "V_ArchiveDir" and "V_FileName" variables selected under the ReadOnly Variables property?

Comment: @Bert-it is there  in readonly variable.file.move(filename,archivedir+filename)this code seems to have an issue.please help on this

Comment: Debug your code and make sure that the two parameters in the Move() method (filename and archivedir+filename) are properly formatted (ie: they have slashes between directory names, etc...).

Comment: If my response helped you solve your problem, please mark it as the answer or add your own so that other uses with the same problem in the future will know the solution thanks.

Comment: @Bert-Thank you very much.It helped alot.Solved my problem:)

Comment: check if fileexists in the folder using script task .when file is available it sends mail which linked to the variable v_fileexists=true but when file is not available it again going to the task which has "file available ".could you help on this if possible. posting the code in the next comment

Comment: String Filepath = Dts.Variables["V_FilePath"].Value.ToString()+Dts.Variables["V_FileName"].Value.ToString();
if (File.Exists(Filepath))
            {
                Dts.Variables["V_fileexists"].Value = true;
               
            }
           
            else
            {
              Dts.Variables["V_fileexists"].Value = false;

           }
            MessageBox.Show(Filepath);
            MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["V_fileexists"].Value.ToString());
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success; 
        }     message box is returning false always for both scenario.